# Rails & Sunspot facets and filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, facet

Pretty much a noobie here, so I appreciate any help someone can give.

I'm trying to add faceting to the search on my site through Sunspot.  Ryan just released a great Railscast which got me started: http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot.  I got that working and was able to add additional facets.  My problem is that the facets are independent of each other.  If I have 3 facets on 3 different attributes, when I select a facet once I already have on selected, I would like to display only results falling into both of those facests.  As of now, it just switches from one facet to the other.  I feel like this shouldn't be that difficult, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I did find this tutorial: http://blog.upubly.com/2011/01/06/using-sunspot-in-your-views/  which I think is doing what I want.  I tried to get this working but, even when I attempt to make it work with just one facet I don't any results listed.  Just the facet name and then nothing else.

Thoughts?

Thank you!!

UPDATE

Here is the code samples of what I am trying to do:

Adjusting the Railscasts code I got this:

In my StylesController:

```
 def index
  @search = Style.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  facet :departmental, :seasonal, :classifier
  with(:departmental, params[:department]) if params[:department].present?
  with(:classifier, params[:classification]) if params[:classification].present?
  with(:seasonal, params[:season]) if params[:season].present?
end
```

In my Style Index view (I know I need to condense this)

```
  = form_tag styles_path, :method => :get do
    %p
      = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
      = submit_tag "Search", :name => nil
  #facets
    %h4 Departments
    %ul
      - for row in @search.facet(:departmental).rows
        %li
          - if params[:department].blank?
            = link_to row.value, :department => row.value
            (#{row.count})
          - else
            %strong= row.value
            (#{link_to "remove", :department => nil})
    %h4 Classifications
    %ul
      - for row in @search.facet(:classifier).rows
        %li
          - if params[:classification].blank?
            = link_to row.value, :classification => row.value
            (#{row.count})
          - else
            %strong= row.value
            (#{link_to "remove", :classification => nil})
    %h4 Seasons
    %ul
      - for row in @search.facet(:seasonal).rows
        %li
          - if params[:season].blank?
            = link_to row.value, :season => row.value
            (#{row.count})
          - else
            %strong= row.value
            (#{link_to "remove", :season => nil})
```

In my Style Model:

```
     searchable do
       text :number, :description, :department, :classification, :season
       string :departmental
       string :classifier
       string :seasonal
     end

     def departmental
       self.department
     end

     def classifier
       self.classification
     end

     def seasonal
       self.season
     end
```

And my version of the upubly code, paired down to just try to get the "seasonal" facet working:

I left the the Search Partial, the Search Model and the SearchHelper the same as in the example.  I tried to mess with the Helper as my Facets will be pulling text values, not just IDs of other Models, but to no avail.  I don't have my various attributes set up as individual Models as I didn't think I needed that functionality, but I am starting to think otherwise.

StylesController:

```
  def index
@title = "All styles"
@search = search = Search.new(params[:search]) # need to set local variable to pass into search method
@search.url = styles_path
@search.facets = [:seasonal]

@solr_search = Style.search do
  keywords search.query
  with(:seasonal, true)
  search.facets.each do |item|
    facet(item)
    with(:seasonal, params[:season]) if params[:season].present?
  end
  any_of do
      # filter by facets
      search.facets.each do |item|
        with(item).all_of( params[item].try(:split, "-") ) if params[item].present?
      end
  end  
  paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end
```

Again, I appreciate the help.  Definitely a noob, but really enjoying the process of building this site.  Stackoverflow has been a HUGE help for me already, so I owe everybody who posts answers on here a big-time thank you.

Comment: faceting tutorial from creator's github account https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot/wiki/Drilling-down-with-facets

Comment: Thank you, I can get faceting working as in the tutorial.  But I am trying to include multiple facets which are not independent.

Comment: Adding a simple, indented sample of how you see this working will help us understand why the suggested solutions aren't working. type in a small sample indented list (heirarchy of facet info), using spaces to indent, then highlight that section of your post and use the {} edit feature at the top of the question input box. ( {} = code block, but it keeps you're indenting intact).

Comment: Thank you, I added my code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

I needed the answer to this myself, and seeing as there seems to be nothing else on the web about it, I decided I'd try to figure it out myself.

First I came to the conclusion through logic, that the controller can handle multiple facets and there's no reasons it cannot, I remembered that the best part about ruby is that it is the most human readable code, try to read your first controller and you'll see that it makes sense that it works. I tested this by manually entering in a query string in url, which returned expected results. Therefore, once I figured that out, I knew the issue resided in my view (which made me facepalm because it's fairly obvious now)

Your example is significantly more complex than mine, and my answer might not 100% meet every requirement but I'm pretty sure it's close. Also your code in your model regarding "departmental" etc is a little redundant in my view

### Controller

```
def index
  @search = Style.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  facet :departmental, :seasonal, :classifier
  with(:departmental, params[:department]) if params[:department].present?
  with(:classifier, params[:classification]) if params[:classification].present?
  with(:seasonal, params[:season]) if params[:season].present?
end
```

### View

```
%h4 Departments
%ul
  - for row in @search.facet(:departmental).rows
    %li
      - if params[:department].blank?
        = link_to row.value, styles_path(
          :department => row.value,
          :classification => (params[:classification] unless params[:season].blank?),
          :season => (params[:season] unless params[:season].blank?))
        (#{row.count})
      - else
        %strong= row.value
        = link_to "remove", styles_path(
          :department => nil,
          :classification => (params[:classification] unless params[:season].blank?),
          :season => (params[:season] unless params[:season].blank?))
```